# Isomorphism between $\mathscr P(\Bbb Q)$ and $\mathscr P(\Bbb Z)$ (power sets of the rationals vs the integers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I had a test today and one question was to mention if there is an isomorphism between  $(\mathscr  P(\Bbb Q),⫃)$ and $(\mathscr  P(\Bbb Z),⫃)$. 
Is anyone can please help me with that one? thanks

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by an isomorphism in this context? An isomorphism for which structures? Or do you only mean a bijection?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the power set of a countable set?

Comment: What does the symbol ⫃ denote here? Without the dot, it would be the standard subset-or-equal symbol. What's the meaning of the dot?

Answer (score 2):

As $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ are both countable, it exists a bijection $\varphi$ between them.

Now define $\Phi : \mathcal P(\mathbb Z) \to \mathcal P(\mathbb Q)$ by $\Phi(A) = \{\varphi(n) \mid n \in A\}$. $\Phi$ is an isomorphism between the power sets endowed with the inclusion order.

Answer (score 2):

Take a bijection $f$ between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the function mapping a set to its image (or the preimage) under $f$ will give an isomorphism between the power sets that preserves the subset relation.